# Could not find a column name keyword in the table

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, bdd, specflow

I have written my first feature file in BDD C# Cucumber. My code builds successfully. I run the feature from Test Explorer by right clicking on the scenario name and selecting Run Selected Tests from the drop down. The browser opens and navigates to the website. But then the following error is shown in Test Explorer:

```
Message: System.indexOutOfRangeException: Could not find a column named 'keyword' in the table.
```

The table looks like this:

```
| Keyword  |
| PS4      |
```

My feature file is as follows:

```
Feature: PS4 Search

@mytag
Scenario: Verify the search Functionality of Search page    
Given I navigate to the page "http://localhost:8080/company"
And I see the page is loaded
When I enter Search Keyword in the Search Text box
| Keyword  |
| PS4      |
And I click on Search Button
Then Search items shows the items related to PS4
```

My steps code is as follows:

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace PS4SearchTest
{
    [Binding]
    public class PS4SearchSteps
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

    [Given(@"I navigate to the page ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenINavigateToThePage(string p0)
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:8080/company");

    }

    [Given(@"I see the page is loaded")]
    public void GivenISeeThePageIsLoaded()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("PS4", driver.Title);
    }

    [When(@"I enter Search Keyword in the Search Text box")]
    public void WhenIEnterSearchKeywordInTheSearchTextBox(Table table)
    {
        string search_text = table.Rows[0]["keyword"].ToString();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys(search_text);
    }

    [When(@"I click on Search Button")]
    public void WhenIClickOnSearchButton()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("BtnG")).Click();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

    [Then(@"Search items shows the items related to PS4")]
    public void ThenSearchItemsShowsTheItemsRelatedToSpecFlow()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("PS4", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3/a")).Text);
        driver.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

Why can it not find the parameter PS4? Is my syntax incorrect for the table of parameters?

Comment: Don't repeat tags in question titles, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says

> Could not find a column named 'keyword' in the table.

Your table has `Keyword`, but in your code you are looking for `keyword`.

To fix it, change

`string search_text = table.Rows[0]["keyword"].ToString();`

to

`string search_text = table.Rows[0]["Keyword"].ToString();`

Comment: Ah the capital K in Keyword.  Case sensitive.  It is working now.  Thank you.